# Poles (i.e., solutions) of 3rd Order Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, control-theory, linear-control

I have a system matrix (A):
$$
        A =\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -C/I & 0 & B/I \\
        0 & -D/K & -E/K \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm taking the determinant:
$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        sI_{n}-A 
        \end{vmatrix} = 0
$$
where $I_{n}$ is the identity matrix.
This yields:

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        s & -1 & 0 \\
        C/I & s & -B/I \\
        0 & D/K & (s+E/K) \\
        \end{vmatrix} = 0
$$

This leads to:
$$ s^2(s+\dfrac{E}{K}) + s(\dfrac{BD}{IK}) + \dfrac{C}{I}(s+\dfrac{E}{K}) $$

Expanding:
$$ s^3 + (\dfrac{E}{K})s^2 + (\dfrac{C}{I}+\dfrac{BD}{KI})s+\dfrac{E}{K} $$

Leaving me with a 3rd order polynomial in $s$.

Solving this now for $s$ is what I would like to do next, in order to determine the poles - i.e., solutions of $ s^3 + (\dfrac{E}{K})s^2 + (\dfrac{C}{I}+\dfrac{BD}{KI})s+\dfrac{E}{K} = 0 $. If anyone can help with this it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to solve by hand or can you use a CAS?

Comment: Update: Mathematica gives some pretty nasty results

Comment: It's going to get messy, but there are closed forms for the roots of cubic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Algebraic_solution

Comment: do you need all solutions? what are you going to use them for?

Comment: If your goal is to prove stability just use the Routh creterion in case you indeed want to find the specific poles you will have hard time calculating them using the closed form for 3rd order polynomials as stated above

Comment: Or you can use Rouché theorem from 1 complex variable over a half plane (to prove stability).

Comment: Thanks for comments! By hand apparently...

Comment: It must be a mistake in the question. As I suspected, there is no way anyone is going to solve that by hand to find the open loop poles.

Comment: Don't you have any conditions on the values of the variables, otherwise it indeed seems pretty impossible to solve by hand?

Comment: You can get linear stability conditions without specific knowledge of the poles using the Routh-Hurwitz algorithm.